# I want my selectInput to show list of dataframes in my global environment

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shinyApp. The first step is that the user will select a dataframe to work upon from the list of available dataframes. To do this I am using a selectInput to get the input from the user. My code is something like this:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "Pivot Tool",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
          inputId = "tableName", label = "Select Table:",
          selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
          choices = c("Select Input",ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame'])
        ),
        <Some other inputs>
      )
    )
  )
```

This does not work. The only option I get to select is the "Select Input" and the dataframes in the global environment is not populated. The snapshot of the output is as follows:
[Snapshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo9cZ.jpg)

The code works perfectly fine if I store the list of available data frames into a variable and then use that variable in the above code. Something like this:

```
temp = ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Pivot Tool",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "tableName", label = "Select Table:",
        selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
        choices = c("Select Input",temp)
      ),
      <Some other inputs>
    )
  )
)
```

The output in this case is as follows:
[Snapshot of the new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/657PZ.jpg)

What am I missing here? I want to generate the list of data frames at the run time and do not want to have a predefined list.

Comment: As pr the [Shiny scoping rules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), if you want for the objects to be shared across UI and server, you should make them available in `global.R`. From the code you've provided it's not clear where the actual call `tamp = (...)` is executed, in `ui.R`?

Comment: I am not sharing objects between UI and server. What I am trying to do here is that I want my UI to fetch list of all the data frames currently available in the global environment which I am failing to do so (demonstrated by the first code).

Comment: You are, you want for the `ui.R` to access environment outside it's scope. **`global.R`** offers that possibility. Your `temp = ` call does not find anything as it does not search global environment from where you run it, have a look at the linked article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in the following manner:

## `global.R`

*As per the [Shiny Scooping Rules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) making use of the `global.R` will make objects available for the server and ui.*

```
dfA <- mtcars
dfB <- airquality

# List dfs
temp = ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']
```

Default Shiny app example with call to `temp` follows below.

### `ui.R`

```
fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # Listing DFs
            selectInput(
                inputId = "tableName", label = "Select Table:",
                selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                choices = c("Select Input", temp)
            ),
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)
```

### `server.R`

```
function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}
```

## *Preview:*

[image: shared data frames]